# How to read text file before GUI program runs

Tags: java, swing, file, user-interface, vector

I've searched through the forums but keep coming up empty for a solution.

I'm making a sort of library with a GUI program. What I want is for it to save entries via a text file. I can create objects fine with the methods I have, and can save them to a file easily. The problem comes from starting up the program again and populating a Vector with values in the text file. The objects I'm adding have a String value, followed by 7 booleans. When I try to load up from file, the String value is empty ("") and all booleans are false.

How do I get it to read the text before starting the rest of the GUI and filling the Vector right?

EDIT: Sorry for being very vague about it all. I'll post the code, but it's about 337 lines long..

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SteamLibraryGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    //For main window
    private JButton exitButton, addEntry, editEntry, removeEntry; 
    private JLabel selectGame, gameCount;
    private JComboBox<String> gameCombo;
    private Vector<Game> gamesList = new Vector<Game>();
    private Vector<String> titleList = new Vector<String>();
    private int numGames = gamesList.size();
    private int selectedGame;

    //For add window
    private JFrame addFrame;
    private JLabel gameTitle = new JLabel("Title:");
    private JTextField titleText = new JTextField(60);
    private JCheckBox singleBox, coopBox, multiBox, cloudBox, controllerBox, achieveBox, pcBox;
    private JButton addGame, addCancel;

    //For edit window
    private JFrame editFrame;
    private JButton editGame, editCancel;

    public SteamLibraryGUI()
    {


        setTitle("Steam Library Organizer");
        addEntry = new JButton("Add a game");
        editEntry = new JButton("Edit a game");
        removeEntry = new JButton("Remove a game");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        selectGame = new JLabel("Select a game:");
        gameCount = new JLabel("Number of games:"+numGames);
        gameCombo = new JComboBox<String>(titleList);

        JPanel selectPanel = new JPanel();
        selectPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        selectPanel.add(selectGame);
        selectPanel.add(gameCombo);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        buttonPanel.add(addEntry);
        buttonPanel.add(editEntry);
        buttonPanel.add(removeEntry);

        JPanel exitPanel = new JPanel();
        exitPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        exitPanel.add(gameCount);
        exitPanel.add(exitButton);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        pane.add(selectPanel);
        pane.add(buttonPanel);
        pane.add(exitPanel);

        addEntry.addActionListener(this);
        editEntry.addActionListener(this);
        removeEntry.addActionListener(this);
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        gameCombo.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==addEntry)
            addEntry();
        if(e.getSource()==editEntry)
            editEntry(gamesList.get(selectedGame));
        if(e.getSource()==removeEntry)
        {
            removeEntry(selectedGame);
            update();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==exitButton)
            exitProg();
        if(e.getSource()==gameCombo)
            {
                selectedGame = gameCombo.getSelectedIndex();
            }
        if(e.getSource()==singleBox)
            singleBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==coopBox)
            coopBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==multiBox)
            multiBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==cloudBox)
            cloudBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==controllerBox)
            controllerBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==achieveBox)
            achieveBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==pcBox)
            pcBox.isSelected();
        if(e.getSource()==addGame)
        {
            gamesList.add(new Game(titleText.getText(), singleBox.isSelected(), coopBox.isSelected(), 
                    multiBox.isSelected(), cloudBox.isSelected(), controllerBox.isSelected(), 
                    achieveBox.isSelected(), pcBox.isSelected()));
            titleList.add(titleText.getText());
            addFrame.dispose();
            update();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==addCancel)
            addFrame.dispose();
        if(e.getSource()==editCancel)
            editFrame.dispose();
        if(e.getSource()==editGame)
        {
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).name = titleText.getText();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).single = singleBox.isSelected();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).coop = coopBox.isSelected();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).multi = multiBox.isSelected();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).cloud = cloudBox.isSelected();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).controller = controllerBox.isSelected();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).achieve = achieveBox.isSelected();
            gamesList.get(selectedGame).pc = pcBox.isSelected();
            titleList.remove(selectedGame);
            titleList.add(titleText.getText());
            editFrame.dispose();
            update();
        }
    }

    public void update()
    {
        Collections.sort(titleList);
        Collections.sort(gamesList);
        gameCombo.updateUI();
        titleText.setText("");
        gameCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        numGames = gamesList.size();
        gameCount.setText("Number of games:"+numGames);
    }

    public void addEntry()
    {
        addFrame = new JFrame("Add Entry");
        addFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addFrame.getContentPane();
        addFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        singleBox = new JCheckBox("Single-Player");
        singleBox.setSelected(false);
        coopBox = new JCheckBox("Coop");
        coopBox.setSelected(false);
        multiBox = new JCheckBox("MultiPlayer");
        multiBox.setSelected(false);
        cloudBox = new JCheckBox("Steam Cloud");
        cloudBox.setSelected(false);
        controllerBox = new JCheckBox("Controller Support");
        controllerBox.setSelected(false);
        achieveBox = new JCheckBox("Achievements");
        achieveBox.setSelected(false);
        pcBox = new JCheckBox("For New PC");
        pcBox.setSelected(false);
        addGame = new JButton("Add game");
        addCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        titlePanel.add(gameTitle);
        titlePanel.add(titleText);

        JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel();
        checkPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        checkPanel.add(singleBox);
        checkPanel.add(coopBox);
        checkPanel.add(multiBox);
        checkPanel.add(cloudBox);
        checkPanel.add(controllerBox);
        checkPanel.add(achieveBox);
        checkPanel.add(pcBox);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(addGame);
        buttonPanel.add(addCancel);

        addFrame.add(titlePanel);
        addFrame.add(checkPanel);
        addFrame.add(buttonPanel);

        singleBox.addActionListener(this);
        coopBox.addActionListener(this);
        multiBox.addActionListener(this);
        cloudBox.addActionListener(this);
        controllerBox.addActionListener(this);
        achieveBox.addActionListener(this);
        pcBox.addActionListener(this);
        addGame.addActionListener(this);
        addCancel.addActionListener(this);

        addFrame.pack();
        addFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void editEntry(Game g)
    {
        editFrame = new JFrame("Edit Entry");
        editFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        editFrame.getContentPane();
        editFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        singleBox = new JCheckBox("Single-Player");
        singleBox.setSelected(g.single);
        coopBox = new JCheckBox("Coop");
        coopBox.setSelected(g.coop);
        multiBox = new JCheckBox("MultiPlayer");
        multiBox.setSelected(g.multi);
        cloudBox = new JCheckBox("Steam Cloud");
        cloudBox.setSelected(g.cloud);
        controllerBox = new JCheckBox("Controller Support");
        controllerBox.setSelected(g.controller);
        achieveBox = new JCheckBox("Achievements");
        achieveBox.setSelected(g.achieve);
        pcBox = new JCheckBox("For New PC");
        pcBox.setSelected(g.pc);
        editGame = new JButton("Edit game");
        editCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        titleText.setText(g.name);

        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        titlePanel.add(gameTitle);
        titlePanel.add(titleText);

        JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel();
        checkPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        checkPanel.add(singleBox);
        checkPanel.add(coopBox);
        checkPanel.add(multiBox);
        checkPanel.add(cloudBox);
        checkPanel.add(controllerBox);
        checkPanel.add(achieveBox);
        checkPanel.add(pcBox);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(editGame);
        buttonPanel.add(editCancel);

        editFrame.add(titlePanel);
        editFrame.add(checkPanel);
        editFrame.add(buttonPanel);

        singleBox.addActionListener(this);
        coopBox.addActionListener(this);
        multiBox.addActionListener(this);
        cloudBox.addActionListener(this);
        controllerBox.addActionListener(this);
        achieveBox.addActionListener(this);
        pcBox.addActionListener(this);
        editGame.addActionListener(this);
        editCancel.addActionListener(this);

        editFrame.pack();
        editFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void removeEntry(int g)
    {
        Object[] options = {"Yes, remove the game", "No, keep the game"};

        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to remove this game from the list?",
                "Remove game?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
        if (n==0)
        {
            gamesList.remove(g);
            titleList.remove(g);
        }
    }

    public void exitProg()
    {
        try 
        {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("games.txt");
            out.flush();
            for(int i=0;i<gamesList.size();i++)
            {

                out.print(gamesList.get(i).toString());
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SteamLibraryGUI frame = new SteamLibraryGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(600,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Scanner in = new Scanner("games.txt");
        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] options = line.split("|");
            Game g = new Game(options[0],Boolean.getBoolean(options[1]),
                    Boolean.getBoolean(options[2]),Boolean.getBoolean(options[3]),
                    Boolean.getBoolean(options[4]),Boolean.getBoolean(options[5]),
                    Boolean.getBoolean(options[6]),Boolean.getBoolean(options[7]));
            frame.gamesList.add(g);
            frame.titleList.add(options[0]);
            System.out.println(g.toString());
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

There's also a Game class, but it's simply 1 String, and then 7 booleans.

Comment: In your `main` method simply call methods that read your file, before creating GUI objects...

Comment: What is the format of your file? How do you assign its content to object variables? Do you use serialization?

Comment: I've tried putting the methods before creating the GUI but it still doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: @JStGermain - Provide more info as requested and post your code.  It's impossible to understand your problem "as is".  Your question will be closed soon unless you make a real effort to clarify it.

Comment: @JStGermain - What's inside "games.txt"? Please post Games class as well or at least its constractor(s). Also try moving all *frame* stuff after your data loading and creation of Game instance.

Comment: I tried having just "Half Life|true|false|false|true|true|true|false" in games.txt. But everytime I try to load up, it only reads in "|false|false|false|false|false|false|false" (as seen in console). Also, constructor for Game is:

Comment: public Game(String title, boolean s, boolean c, boolean m, boolean cl, boolean co, boolean a, boolean p)
  {
   name = title;
   single = s;
   coop = c;
   multi = m;
   cloud = cl;
   controller = co;
   achieve = a;
   pc = p;
  }

Answer (score 0):

There were two significant bugs in the code. First, `Scanner` was constructed with a string parameter (which means that the Scanner scanned the string, not the file named by the string). Second, the pipe character "|" is a regular expression metacharacter. That is important because `line.split()` splits on regular expressions. Thus, the "|" has to be escaped. The `main()` function works fine if it is written as follows (with debugging output code included to show that each step is working correctly):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SteamLibraryGUI frame = new SteamLibraryGUI();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(600,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("games.txt"));
        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println("line = ");
            String line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] options = line.split("\\|");
            System.out.println("Options = ");
            for (String s : options)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            Game g = new Game(options[0],Boolean.getBoolean(options[1]),
                Boolean.getBoolean(options[2]),Boolean.getBoolean(options[3]),
                Boolean.getBoolean(options[4]),Boolean.getBoolean(options[5]),
                Boolean.getBoolean(options[6]),Boolean.getBoolean(options[7]));
            frame.gamesList.add(g);
            frame.titleList.add(options[0]);
            System.out.println(g.toString());
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException x) 
    {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
}
```

There is one other important Gotcha: The method `exitProg()` writes the "games.txt" file out again before the program finishes. This creates a problem if the file was read incorrectly in the first place because the wrong data will be written back to the file. During testing, this means that even when the reading code has been corrected, it will still read the erroneous data that was written from a previous test run.

My preference in this situation is would be to isolate all the reading and writing code for "game.txt" inside the `Game` class (which makes it easier to verify that the reading and writing formats are identical) and only write the code to write the data back out once I'd written and tested the reading code, which would avoid this Gotcha.